# Executing StartSoner.bat is stucked after "Process[ce] is up" line

Tags: sonarqube5.6

I'm running StartSonar.bat file. it process up to line "2016.06.22 09:36:12 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is up" line and stucked. but as i see some errors are encountered before that. how to resole this and getting StartSonar.bat executing.

```
2016.06.22 09:50:06 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1466569198149] 
started
2016.06.22 09:50:06 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1466569198149] recovered[6] indices into cluster_state
2016.06.22 09:50:08 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2016.06.22 09:50:08 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;F:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer F:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\temp\sq-process8289301176774396331properties
2016.06.22 09:50:10 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2016.06.22 09:50:10 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: F:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\web
2016.06.22 09:50:10 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.06.22 09:50:10 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.06.22 09:50:12 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6 / 074f3d1169f9688d15af4aff67e7e672cbeed782
2016.06.22 09:50:14 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.06.22 09:50:14 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: F:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\data
2016.06.22 09:50:14 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.06.22 09:50:15 WARN  web[o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2016.06.22 09:50:16 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: F:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6
2016.06.22 09:50:17 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1466569198149] loaded [], sites []
2016.06.22 09:50:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 5.0 / 17ddb09047940791828dcb70c9e225f006ab11aa
2016.06.22 09:50:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.2 / a713dd64daf8719ba4e7f551f9a1966c62690c17
2016.06.22 09:50:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 3.13.1 / cf0f0c950ba3e83a87c7fe11c6ff7e63f4864bd9
2016.06.22 09:50:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JavaScript / 2.11 / a9b1afa9ceef7079811779d9efc5f8026acb1400
2016.06.22 09:50:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.3 / aff503d48bc77b07c2b62abf93249d0a20bd355c
2016.06.22 09:50:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
2016.06.22 09:50:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2016.06.22 09:50:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification  service started (delay 60 sec.)
2016.06.22 09:50:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2016.06.22 09:50:21 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2016.06.22 09:50:23 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register   measure filters
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboards
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index activities
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index issues
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index tests
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index users
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index views
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_05-b13 [Windows 8-amd64]
2016.06.22 09:50:24 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2016.06.22 09:50:38 INFO  web[jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2016.06.22 09:50:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.InitFilter@3099252e [pattern=/sessions/init/*]
2016.06.22 09:50:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter@77a73abb [pattern=/oauth2/callback/*]
2016.06.22 09:50:38 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.06.22 09:50:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2016.06.22 09:50:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2016.06.22 09:50:38 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2016.06.22 09:50:38 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;./lib/ce/*;F:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer F:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\temp\sq-process6396047397653939190properties
2016.06.22 09:50:40 INFO  ce[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
2016.06.22 09:50:40 INFO  ce[o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine starting up...
2016.06.22 09:50:40 INFO  ce[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6 / 074f3d1169f9688d15af4aff67e7e672cbeed782
2016.06.22 09:50:40 INFO  ce[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.06.22 09:50:40 WARN  ce[o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2016.06.22 09:50:41 INFO  ce[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: F:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6
2016.06.22 09:50:42 INFO  ce[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1466569198149] loaded [], sites []
2016.06.22 09:50:43 INFO  ce[o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Load plugins
2016.06.22 09:50:44 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.q.PurgeCeActivities] Delete the Compute Engine tasks created before Fri Dec 25 09:50:44 IST 2015
2016.06.22 09:50:44 INFO  ce[o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine is up
2016.06.22 09:50:45 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is up
```